# Windows 10 Home - Develop a little Android App

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to start a Hello World Android project on my computer with the operating system Windows 10 Home . I have configured the environment to develop and I have installed an emulator and the android sdk. But the application doesn't start on the emulator. I want to activate the Hyper-V feature to get better performance:

`dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All`

And then I am getting the error:

`Hyper-V Feature is unknown and unable to install.`

I know that for develop should I have the windows 10 pro edition. But can I do anything to develop little applications with my visual studio 17 and my windows 10 home edition? I cannot start an Hello World application on the emulator!

Comment: Use Android's accelerated x86 emulators via Intel HAXM and Hyper-V is not needed.

Comment: But why compiling is so slow? The build is extremely slow

Comment: What are your PC's hardware specs?

Comment: Processor: Intel Core i7-7500U - RAM 8 GB 64Bit-OS

Comment: that should be "OK", *not great not that bad*, builds are disk-intensive so SSDs help a lot... turn on diagnostic level logging in MSbuild and at the end of the build you will get a break down of the times for each build step/task.

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to your Windows version. If you are using AMD processor and it is old, probably your processor doesn't support Hyper-V. You can use BlueStacks with Android Nougat 7.1 version. [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com)

Comment: Ok, I am going to install BlueStacks and trying with it

Comment: how can I deploy an application from visual studio 2017 on the BlueStacks? I don't find any information about that

Comment: Keep open the BlueStacks. You'll see in emulator section I think.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to activate the Hyper-V feature

`Hyper-V` on `Windows 10` **only works under a specific set of operating system and hardware configurations**. This document shows the Hyper-V requirements: [Windows 10 Hyper-V System Requirements.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/reference/hyper-v-requirements)

> The Hyper-V role cannot be installed on:
>
> - Windows 10 Home

As the document said, you cannot add the `Hyper-V` feature on your Windows Home Edition.

> But can I do anything to develop little applications with my visual studio 17 and my windows 10 home edition?

The answer is **Yes**.

You could refer to the document: [Hardware Acceleration for Emulator Performance (HAXM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin#accelerating-with-haxm).